# android speed limit on streets

Tags: android, google-maps, location

im using `location.getSpeed()` to get the speed from the GPS my question is how can i get the speed limit on each street so i can compare it with my speed

thanks

Comment: Use the camera to read traffic signs in order to figure out the current speed limit.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is no *simple* way, either you have to make a collection (map) with the values and compare it with current GPS position or you can buy from one of the companies dealing with this.

Answer (score 2):

[NAVTEQ](http://www.nn4d.com/site/global/home/p_home.jsp) seems to be one reputable company that serves up this sort of data. The developer page (linked previously) should give you more information on this. It's not likely to be free; you'd have to contact them to work out a licensing deal of some sort.